# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError!!1

Tags: java

```
   package OOPS.constructors;

   class Student{
      String name;
      int age;

       public void printInfo(){
           System.out.println(this.name);
           System.out.println(this.age);
       };

       Student(String name,int age){
           this.name = name;
           this.age = age;
       }
   }

   public class Parameterized{
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s2 = new Student("yash", 21);
        s2.printInfo();   
       }
   }
```

here the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: OOPS.constructors.Student.(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at OOPS.constructors.Parameterized.main(Parameterized.java:20)

I dont know how to solve this error so anyone can help me

Comment: FYI, the code works ok for me.

Comment: Perhaps... remove the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the `printInfo()` method code block in the `Student` class.